# SIP communication open source

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, voip

I was trying to implement the SIP concept in my app. For that I found [PORTSIP](http://www.portsip.com/voipsdk.html) sample code. It is working fine with the given credentials (domain, username, password). But it is a trial version, not an open source.

Does there any open source for the VoIP calling. Please help me out that what steps should I follow to implement the audio calling via SIP.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this three options so far:

1. The [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html) is good, and not trial.
2. [Siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/) - SIP -VoIP for iPhone and iPod Touch
3. [IDoubs](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/) - VideoPhone for iOS (iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch) and MAC OS X

To run **Linphone** project without any problems (build using SDK7 XCode5), try the following:

1. First download [build
   files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DwszanZcPhV0doNm5rMHdWa28/edit?usp=sharing)
   and unzip them.
2. Place the folder `liblinphone-sdk` in the main folder of project.
3. Open `linphone.xcodeproj` and run the linphone project.

Comment: I already checked all the above links given by you. but didn't find any proper source code. Please provide if you have anyone.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout isn't that the source code to Siphon?

Comment: What do you mean by proper source code? All of this has SIP client implemented.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert yes this is.

Comment: @dimimpou: There is no option display to download the source code through this link:code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout. Please tell how to download all the classes.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert I have downloaded the source code from code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout but it is giving the error of IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h file not found. how to remove it

Comment: @Sudha which file are you build? Have you follow the steps provided in readme?

Comment: @Vishal there is the svn link which you can checkout the whole project.

Comment: @Sudha follow the steps in this [README](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxvrzetaxfd739m/readme.txt), and tell me if you have any issue. Why you don't try linphone? Its better, full customizable & easy to build.

Comment: @Sudha The LinPhone is an open source. It is working absolutely fine for me. What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: @PiyushDubey I am not getting all the header files. 7-8 header files are missing and also not able to find these files over internet. i.e. msspeexec.h, sftp.h, config.h, tips.h, tips_rand.h. Please send these header files if you have in your app

Comment: @Sudha If header files are missing probably you have done some mistake in the process of compiling the project.

Comment: @dimimpou I tried my best. But don't know why it is giving the error i.e. ortp file not found

Comment: @Sudha you telling about Linphone or siphon project?

Comment: @dimimpou regarding Linphone project

Comment: Try this: http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/, if you still have problem take [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhud68re9he36uw/liblinphone-sdk.zip) and let me know when you download the file, in order to help you with rest steps.

Comment: @Sudha The files you are asking are also missing in my project, but it is working fine without any error. I think you could make a try without those files also or download the code form link dimimpou has shared.

Comment: @PiyushDubey I have made every try but not get any success. Can you shared compiled code If you have

Comment: @Sudha have you try steps of the link that i have give you? The files almost uploaded, try to download.

Comment: @dimimpou I am trying buddy

Comment: @dimimpou it is showing that this file is uploading

Comment: Take the files using [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DwszanZcPhV0doNm5rMHdWa28/edit?usp=sharing), dropbox appears to be slower. I'll update my answer to help you what to do with this.

Comment: @Sudha are you ok with the files? Did those work for the project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for open source implementation of the SIP stack, 
take a look at : [OSIP](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/osip/)

You can create your own single user SIP Phone, or a SIP call server to handle 100s of calls..

eXosip is higher level wrapper for convenience in case you don't want to go too deep into the stack code.

For RTP, you can use [oRTP](http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/ortp.html)

Linphone is developed using osip/eXosip/oRTP stack.